# How to solve this oscillator problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, inductor

I have done some calculations which I have shown below here i assumed that total current supplied by battery is I
here is the problem[image]

Comment: It's not a sustainable oscillator - if you want to design an oscillator or need help understanding the tuned tank of an oscillator you should embed a picture of a standard oscillator type like `Colpitts` or `Hartley` (there are others too). The oscillations will start in your circuit but, they will die down after several alternating cycles. You need to be clearer about what you require.

Comment: What you really have above is a low pass filter than can create decaying oscillations. If you want help solving it then maybe [my crappy website](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20BPF/RCL%20BPF.html) and the engine can help you visualize what happens when you make a step change of battery supply at the input.

Comment: Yeah its not one but antonie 51 wanted to get credit so i reuploaded this

Comment: @Andyaka thankyou so much you have been like a real teacher to me sir i will surely explore your website

Comment: @Andyaka but thankyou so much for the help

Comment: @Damstridium Don't worry about ... I don't search "reputation", Thanks. <<< Help each other ... for the "good and sake of all" ! >>> Don't know if it is the "right sentence". Somebody, in the old times, says something as this.

Comment: @Antonio51 Thankyou for helping me thankyou so much may god bless you brother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the current supplied by the source is given by:

$$\text{i}_\text{i}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{R}+\left(\text{sL}\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}\right]_{\left(t\right)}=\hat{\text{u}}\int_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{CLs}^2+1}{\text{CLRs}^2+\text{Ls}+\text{R}}\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\tag1$$

Where \$\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\cdot\right]_{\left(t\right)}\$ is the inverse [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) and I used the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the Laplace transform.